# Access dynamic named variables inside a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a lot of variables inside a loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    globals()[f"variables{i}"] = i
```

perfect, so now I have `variables0 = 0`, `variables1 = 1`, `variables2 = 2`, etc. But now, i want to access each one of them with a loop and I don't really know how to do that.

I know it's not gonna work, but anyways I've tried:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(variables{i})
```

Anyone know how can I point the right variable name inside a loop?

Comment: You can access them in the same way you created them, via `globals()['var_name']`. A list or dict would probably be more appropriate here though

Answer (score -1):

You can use `gloabals` to dynamically acces to the values. No need of evaluate strings. You need to filter the dictionary by name, for example with a `.startswith('variables'))` and iterate over the list of key-value pairs representing the dictionary. I save the values in a list but it depends on your needs (you can just make a `print`).

```
# add variables danamically to global name
for i in range(10):
    globals()[f"variables{i}"] = i

# access to variables (and for ex store them in a list...)
d_vars = []
glbs = list((name, value) for name, value in globals().items() if name.startswith('variables'))

for i, (k, v) in enumerate(glbs):
    if k == (name:=f'variables{i}'):
        d_vars.append(v)
        # print(f'{name} = {v}')
    
print(d_vars)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use dictionary in this case

```
dict = {}
for i in range(0,10):
    dict[f'variable{i}'] = i
```

Or to answer your above question, you can use eval:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(eval(f'variables{i}'))
```

Mostly dictionary method is preferable.

Comment: A list with `variable[i]` is the right solution, not eval.

Comment: don't shadow built-in functions `dict`

Comment: @GastonMalvinas let me know if this works for you. :-)